# Um ihr zu öffnen

Tags: grammatical-case

I am reading a novel in German and I have come across a sentence where I don't understand the grammar. A man notices a woman standing at the entrance door to his shop and gets up to let her in, "*um ihr zu öffnen*" it reads in the book. *Um* usually takes the accusative and so if it is meant "to open the door" it should read *"um sie zu öffnen"* surely.

Is "*um ihr zu öffnen*" some way of saying "to open it (the door) for her"?

Comment: This isn't *um*, the preposition, at all. This is its twin brother, *um...zu*, the subordinating conjunction, which takes subclauses and not noun phrases, therefore it has no influence on case whatsoever. The dative is introduced into the equation by the verb *öffnen* instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is "um ihr zu öffnen" some way of saying "to open (the door) for her"?

Yes, exactly. You are also right, that *to open the door* translates to *um sie/die Tür zu öffnen*. But as you open the door *for her*, a dative object is necessary, hence *ihr*. I guess the *sie/die Tür* is not necessary because of the context, or the sentence prior to this. If you want to include a reference to *the door* as accusative object, you could just say:

> um sie ihr zu öffnen 
>   um ihr die Tür zu öffnen

Answer (score 2):

I want to expand a little on @KilianFoth's comment.

*um...zu...* in German is similar to "in order to" in English:

[BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/german/grammar/verbsinfinitivesrev1.shtml)

> Um... zu... means 'in order to', for example:
> *Ich fahre nach Deutschland, um mein Deutsch zu verbessern* -> I'm going to Germany in order to improve my German.
>
> *Um schlank zu werden, habe ich eine Diät gemacht* -> In order to get slim, I went on a diet.
>
> ...Um starts the section. The infinitive verb is at the end and zu comes just before. Any left overs go in-between um and zu.

There are also some SO threads discussing *um...zu*:

[When is 'to' translated with “um zu”, when with “zu”](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/3976/19081)
[Preposition following “um” in an “um … zu” construction](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33326/preposition-following-um-in-an-um-zu-construction)

[BBC - Infinitive Construction](https://www.bbc.com/bitesize/guides/z39tsg8/revision/1)
[Zum vs. Um...Zu](https://yourdailygerman.com/use-of-zu-and-um-zu/)